# Open file in Python that the open() function cannot handle

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, encoding

In python, trying to open a file path that was obtained using glob.glob i suspect that the path contains characters with a different encoding to what open() can handle not sure tho. i can skip the file but i need a way to detect the characters causing the issue. or rather a method to open the file anyway would be perfect.

trying to open many files one of which with the name
`.\\input\\537700 Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song)\\Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song) (fieryrage) [mk's hard].osu`
will not open. got an error instead ):

```
files = glob.glob(folder+'*.osu', recursive = True) 

for file in files:

        inputFile = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ".\\input\\537700 Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song)\\Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song) (fieryrage) [mk's hard].osu"
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan McClen\Documents\SliderToCircleOsuMapConversion\new.py", line 19, in <module>
    inputFile = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ".\\input\\537700 Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song)\\Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song) (fieryrage) [mk's hard].osu"
```

Comment: Does the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760546/python-filenotfounderror-from-glob-output-full-path-to-file-is-correct) help at all?

Comment: You may have to change a policy setting or registry key to enable long file support in windows. See [Removing the MAX_PATH Limitation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation)

Comment: It seems odd that you have a **directory** named `37700 Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song)`, and the file itself is **also** named `Raven-Symone, Anneliese van der Pol, Orlando Brown - That's So Raven! (Theme Song) (fieryrage) [mk's hard]`.  Are you **sure** that is correct?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print(os.listdir('input'))` ?

Comment: Thanks so much everyone it was file path limit (:. also john the file has a similar name as it is part of the map files for game and thats just the naming system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was caused from windows cap on file path
[max path limiation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation)